# Python pandas: pivot DataFrame columns in rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have a pandas DataFrame as following, showing the scores of students in multiple subjects:

```
       Name    Subject    Score
0       Tom          A       91
1       Tom          B       92
2       Tom          C       93
3       Bob          A       94
4       Bob          C       95
5       Ali          B       96
6       Ali          C       97
```

Note that not every student has scores in all subjects. I want to pivot it into a DataFrame like this:

```
      Name     A     B     C
0      Tom    91    92    93
1      Bob    94          95    
2      Ali          96    97
```

The goals to achieve in this pivot:

1. group the scores by 'Name'
2. insert columns of subjects
3. arrange the scores at the crossing space of Name and subjects

I'm new to pandas but I looked into DataFrame.pivot_table(), while unfortunately couldn't figure out the right way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were right on with using a [pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html#pandas-dataframe-pivot-table) to solve this:

```py
df = df.pivot_table(index='Name', values='Score', columns='Subject') \
    .reset_index() \
    .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  Name     A     B     C
0  Ali   NaN  96.0  97.0
1  Bob  94.0   NaN  95.0
2  Tom  91.0  92.0  93.0
```

---

[Pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html#pandas-dataframe-pivot) also works in this case:

```py
df = df.pivot(index='Name', values='Score', columns='Subject') \
    .reset_index() \
    .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution

```
import pandas as pd
df= DATAFRAME [ as yours]
df1=df.pivot(index='Name',columns = 'Subject', values = 'Score').fillna('').round(decimals=0).astype(object)
```

Output
[image]